# How to automatically adjust the position of a layout image using plotly?

Tags: python, html, plotly, graphical-logo

I am trying to add a logo to a **plotly** figure that I then save as a **html** file.

I adjusted the x and y coordinates to display the logo in the top left corner of my html page.

[image]

However, when I open the same html file from a computer whose screen has a higher resolution, the logo is cropped:

[image]

Here is a MRE:

```
from PIL import Image
import plotly.graph_objects as go

def create_report():
    WeylandLogo = Image.open("Weyland.jpg")
    fig = go.Figure()
    fig.add_layout_image(
    dict(
        source=WeylandLogo,
        xref="paper", yref="paper",
        x=0, y=1.05,
        sizex=0.2, sizey=0.2,
        xanchor="left", yanchor="bottom"
        )
    )
    fig.write_html("cornbread.html")

create_report()
```

According to [plotly's website](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/annotations/#layout-annotations-items-annotation-xref), setting `xref` and `yref` to `paper` allows to use "normalized" coordinates.

> If set to "paper", the `x` position refers to the distance from the
> left of the plotting area in normalized coordinates where "0" ("1")
> corresponds to the left (right).

I thought that this would automatically adjust the position of the logo, but apparently this is not the case. What parameters should I use?

Comment: I haven't actually tried it, but wouldn't it be improved by specifying a standard height and width size for the `paper`? e.g.`fig.update_layout(height=400,width=600)`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, @r-beginners, it actually solved my problem. If you turn your comment into an answer, I will gladly accept it.

Comment: On a side note, fixing the `paper` `height` and `width` solves the cropping issue but also prevents the actual subfigures from resizing dynamically. This makes me wonder whether plotly is actually suited to create interactive reports or whether I should start exploring other options.

Comment: I think there is a trade-off between figure limitation and dynamic resizing. A minor improvement would be to place the logo in the upper right corner (e.g., where the legend is placed). The width would change dynamically if only the height is limited.

Comment: Also, a larger margin at the top of the graph might be a fundamental improvement. `fig.update_layout(margin=dict(t=200,b=0,r=0,l=0))`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I gave it a shot and it helped.